# How can I find out which databases, schemas and tables were created by default?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to find out which databases, schemas and tables were created by default. I was wondering how to do that?

I use `\l` but can't tell from its output. Thanks.

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql


postgres=# \l
                                   List of databases
     Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
--------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 linuxhowtodb | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 students     | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
              |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
              |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(5 rows)
```

Comment: It feels Too Specific for SO - which isn't necessarily a problem, but voting to move to DBAs.

Answer (score 2):

The databases `template0`, `template1` and `postgres` are created by default when you `initdb`.

The database `postgres` is for administrative connections, `template1` will be used as default template when you create a new database without specifying an explicit template, and `template0` is the template you use if you need a *really* empty database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give an extremely general answer to the question of "how can I tell": you can't.

"Created by default" could mean various things, but often it just means "initialised by the installer"; there is generally no reason for the system to keep track of which things were created by the installer, and which by the user.

The user might even be able to change or remove things which the installer created, with or without impacting normal operation of the system.

In the case of PostgreSQL, there are indeed many objects which are created by the installer. Some of them must continue to exist for safe operation of the system - you can remove the definitions of "built-in" operators and functions, but are likely to be left with a somewhat broken system if you do. Others are simply useful for the user - the `postgres` database is by convention completely empty, and used by tools when connecting to perform server maintenance commands.

The only sure way to find out everything created by default is to do a clean install of the latest version of the software, and immediately look at what it contains before adding any of your own data. The best way to find out what those are all for is to read through the manual. That applies to PostgreSQL, but also to pretty much any other software.