# Does the SQL standard specifies other schemas, catalogs, or tables besides INFORMATION_SCHEMA?

Tags: sql

The SQL standard specifies `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` as a schema to provide information about other schemas in the same catalog.

I wonder if the SQL standard also specifies other schemas, catalogs, or tables, which are by default created by a DBMS  that is compliant with the SQL standard?

I was [looking at PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48272844/156458), which is supposed to be the most faithful implementation of the SQL standard, but don't know how to find out such information that I am asking for above.

Thanks.

Comment: No, the standard only specifies `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.  That is why it exists.

Comment: I was [looking at PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48272844/156458), which is supposed to be the most faithful implementation of the SQL standard, but don't know how to find out such information that I am asking for above.